symfony messenger process stucked
I am using symfony messenger with supervisor to generate a lot of PDFs or doing a lot of tasks.
Regularly, my consumer process gets stuck, and I have to restart it manually
This morning, when i came to work, my pod was consuming 50% of CPU
In the pod, the ps -aux command shows my process consuming 99.8% of CPU
strace on this process shows it is doing nothing
The command of my worker is configured to restart each hour, but I think it is considering it does something because the process was alive since 65 hours
here is the config:
[program:messenger-consume-reglement]
command=php /var/www/html/bin/console messenger:consume reglement_queue --time-limit=3600 --failure-limit=1
user=www-data
numprocs=1
startsecs=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d


I'm not too familiar with the specific of --time-limit= maybe your process is not ending so even if your time limit is reached it does not end ? You could also impose a message limit and/or memory limit on your consumer
